How to enter on the open of a new bar (not wait for it to close)?
I want to create a "gap" trading strategy - i.e., when the open price of a new bar is different from the close of the previous bar.
The entry should be when the new bar opens... however I am having trouble doing that, as the default behaviour seems to be to execute trades on the close of a bar.
Here is an example:

Could use some help with the basic treatment needed.
EDIT:
Do I need some kind of combination of checking if barstate.isnew and barstate.isconfirmed in order to do this?

No, the default behavior opens trades on the open of the next bar. You must have process_orders_on_close = true in your strategy() or checked that option under the Properties tab.
Make sure your strategy() call does not have it and the option under the Properties tab is unselected.

Please note that, the entry will take place on the open of the next candle. So, if there is a gap on the current bar, you will enter the trade on the open of the next bar.

Amazing thank you. I think this is what I am looking for, but will confirm it solves my question in regards to my script, at which point I will either accept my answer or update my question if needed. Thanks again. =)

Do you want to enter a short trade on the blue line on that green candle or on the red candle next to it (where it currently goes long)?

The former (entry should be on blue line of green bar)... I.e., as soon as an open is different from a close value, enter a trade in the opposite direction. It is still not working as-is. Thanks

That's not possible. A market order can either be placed on the close of the current bar or on the open of the next bar. If you really want to enter a trade on the open of the current bar, I suggest you convert your strategy into an indicator.
